# mod_rewrite pull images from main domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to get all the template images and css files in a sub domain from the main domain, so that I don't need to duplicate everything.

This rule is working for images in the root folder but not sub directories.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub.domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg|gif|png|css|js|txt|ico|pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

How can I modify the code so that all the specified extensions directs to the main domain even if those files are in different folders and not only in the root folder.

Comment: What you need is the `<base>` tag

Comment: Using the `<base>` tag can cause more problems then it actually solves sometimes – I wouldn’t use it whenever it can be avoided.

Comment: @CBroe I would wish to know in what way it causes problem? As am using it, so do I need to use absolute instead of relative URL's?

Comment: @user2248639 What is the full addresses of the existed images, and where full addresses do you want them to be remapped?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.+\.(?:jpg|gif|png|css|js|txt|ico|pdf))$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [NC,R=permanent]
```

That should grab the entire request path and filename and then append it to the main domain for the redirect.

If you're using httpd.conf instead, you need to add a forward-slash to the RewriteRule match pattern, immediately after the `^` character.